# Issue with java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays, indexing

I'm new in Java programming and I'm trying to write a method that orders an array in crescent or decrescent mode.

```
public static int[] orderArray(int[] v, boolean mode) {
    int newArray[] = {};
    for (int i=0; i<v.length; i++) if (mode) newArray[i] = getMin(v, i); else newArray[i] = getMax(v, i);
    return newArray;
}
```

So in another class I put:

```
int[] myArray = {5,3,4,1,6};
//Call the method
int[] newOrdArray = Vettori.orderArray(myArray, true);
    System.out.println(Vettori.printArray(newOrdArray, ","));
```

There are some methods that I wrote before and I'm using to reach my objective.
I mean the methods: printArray, getMin and getMax

```
public static int getMin(int[] v, int pos) { //getMin
    int minimum = 0;
    if (v.length>0)
    for (int i=pos;i<v.length;i++) {
        if(i==pos) minimum=v[i];
        else if(v[i]<=minimum) minimum=v[i];
    }
    return minimum;
}

public static int getMax(int[] v, int pos) { //getMax
    int max = 0;
    if (v.length>0)
    for (int i=pos;i<v.length;i++) {
        if(i==pos) max=v[i];
        else if(v[i]>=max) max=v[i];
    }
    return max;
}

public static String printArray(int[] v, String separator) { //printArray
    String stampa = "";
    if (v.length>0) {
        boolean insert_sep = true;
        for (int i=0;i<v.length;i++) {
            insert_sep = v[i]!=v.length;
            if (insert_sep) stampa+=Integer.toString(v[i])+separator;
            else stampa+=Integer.toString(v[i]);
        }
        stampa = stampa.substring(0, stampa.length()-1);
    } else stampa = "Invalid array!";
    return stampa;
}
```

When I compile the code and try to ordinate the array, the program throws the java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exception. I'm trying to find the issue in my code, but I can't...
Here the output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at Utili.Vettori.ordinaVettore(Vettori.java:335)
at mainProgram.main(mainProgram.java:24)
```

Comment: Your code doesn't show line numbers, what line of above code is the error for?

Comment: could you minimize your problem just to the point where the exception occurs, it will help to understand your problem and why you do receive the eror

Comment: You haven't posted `Utility.Vettori.ordinaVettore`, which is where your stack trace originates. Also consider just using `Arrays.sort`. And English code.

Comment: I suggest you properly indent your `orderArray` code as you did in the other methods. There is no bonus for minimizing number of lines in your code, and it severely hurts readability. It will also pinpoint the part of that loop-if-else that causes the issue.

Comment: from exception i'm guessing your array is empty, can you show is which line cause you this exception

Answer (score 0):

Initialize array in orderArray method before adding any elements:

```
int[] newArray = new int[v.length];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in the `orderArray` method where you have created an array of size 0 then attempted to access elements of it causing an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Change line

```
int newArray[] = {};
```

to create a new integer array of the same size as your method parameter `v`.

```
int newArray[] = new int[v.length];
```

Your resulting method should look like this

```
public static int[] orderArray(int[] v, boolean mode) {
    int newArray[] = new int[v.length];
    for (int i=0; i<v.length; i++) if (mode) newArray[i] = getMin(v, i); else newArray[i] = getMax(v, i);
    return newArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

found your problem

```
 int newArray[] = {};
 for (int i=0; i<v.length; i++) if (mode) newArray[i] = getMin(v, i); 
else newArray[i] = getMax(v, i);
```

you are creating empty array, and then try to access fields which are not exist

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simple, on your "**orderArray(int[] v, boolean mode)**" method, you did not initialize your new array, and thus you get ArrayOutOfBoundException.

Here, you have to make these changes, I've commented out the errorneous line and added a new line for the array initialization;

```
//      int newArray[] = {};
        int newArray[] = new int[v.length];
```

The complete corrected code is as below;

```
public class TestArrayOrder {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] myArray = { 5, 3, 4, 1, 6 };

        // Call the method
        int[] newOrdArray = orderArray(myArray, true);

        System.out.println(printArray(newOrdArray, ","));

    }

    public static int[] orderArray(int[] v, boolean mode) {
        // int newArray[] = {};             //you should initialize the array
        int newArray[] = new int[v.length]; // array initialization

        for (int i = 0; i < v.length; i++)
            if (mode)
                newArray[i] = getMin(v, i);
            else
                newArray[i] = getMax(v, i);

        return newArray;
    }

    public static int getMin(int[] v, int pos) { // getMin
        int minimum = 0;
        if (v.length > 0)
            for (int i = pos; i < v.length; i++) {
                if (i == pos)
                    minimum = v[i];
                else if (v[i] <= minimum)
                    minimum = v[i];
            }
        return minimum;
    }

    public static int getMax(int[] v, int pos) { // getMax
        int max = 0;
        if (v.length > 0)
            for (int i = pos; i < v.length; i++) {
                if (i == pos)
                    max = v[i];
                else if (v[i] >= max)
                    max = v[i];
            }
        return max;
    }

    public static String printArray(int[] v, String separator) { // printArray
        String stampa = "";
        if (v.length > 0) {
            boolean insert_sep = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
                insert_sep = v[i] != v.length;
                if (insert_sep)
                    stampa += Integer.toString(v[i]) + separator;
                else
                    stampa += Integer.toString(v[i]);
            }
            stampa = stampa.substring(0, stampa.length() - 1);
        } else
            stampa = "Invalid array!";
        return stampa;
    }

}
```

Here is the output for the "**true**" mode call of your **orderArray** method;

```
1,1,1,1,6
```

And the output for "**false**" mode;

```
6,6,6,6,6
```

Hope that it helps.